# How Firebase realtime database works?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is a lot of information about how to use the Firebase realtime database, but I want to know how it works (from behind).

What is the key architecture factor that allows Firebase to store and deliver the data so fast?

Comment: just guessing: there should be some kind of push technology behind, like https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API

Comment: They use a combination of Netty.io, long running sockets and polling. Try listening to this podcast for more details - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NkJiqtJvu0&list=PLIivdWyY5sqJOTOszXDZh3XustjvTsrmQ&index=117